# Can not boot into hera live iso, grub entry fails

Tags: boot, release-hera

**My system spec
output of neofetch command**

```
OS: elementary OS 5.1 Hera x86_64 
Host: H310M S2 2.0
Kernel: 5.0.0-37-generic 
Uptime: 34 mins 
Packages: 1836 
Shell: bash 4.4.20 
Resolution: 1024x768 
DE: Pantheon 
WM: Mutter(Gala) 
Theme: Elementary [GTK3] 
Icons: Elementary [GTK3] 
Terminal: io.elementary.t 
CPU: Intel i5-9400F (6) @ 4.100GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GT 1030 
Memory: 1230MiB / 7921MiB
```

BIOS Settings:

```
Fastboot off
secure boot off
```

I have a running elementary OS 5.1([hera](/questions/tagged/hera)) system which is fine. Installed using bootable USB using rufus.

I want to have a test elementary OS wherein I can do trials before doing it in working system.
I usually do this by booting into ISO live system, do the testing and if comfortable implement it in working system.

**My grub entry in 40_custom**

```
menuentry "Elementary OS 5.1 Hera ISO" {
        set root='(hd1,13)'
        set isofile='/anivaarya-linux-distros/ele5.1/elementaryos-5.1-stable.20191202.iso'
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f3db7e9a-1e71-4493-b26c-4b092a1e172e
        loopback loop $isofile
        linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile quiet splash threadirqs noprompt noeject  pci=nomsi,noaer 
        initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}

menuentry "Ubuntu 19.10 ISO" {
        set root='(hd1,13)'
        set isofile='/anivaarya-linux-distros/ubuntu1910/ubuntu-19.10-desktop-amd64.iso'
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f3db7e9a-1e71-4493-b26c-4b092a1e172e
        loopback loop $isofile
        linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed iso-scan/filename=$isofile quiet splash threadirqs noprompt noeject pci=nomsi noaer 
        initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
}

menuentry "Zorin 15 Core ISO" {
        set root='(hd1,13)'
        set isofile='/anivaarya-linux-distros/zorin15/Zorin-OS-15-Core-64-bit-r1.iso'
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f3db7e9a-1e71-4493-b26c-4b092a1e172e
        loopback loop $isofile
        linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile quiet splash threadirqs noprompt noeject pci=nomsi,noaer nvidia-zorin 
        initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz4
}
```

I added ubuntu 1910 and Zorin OS 15 because I am able to boot to them. But elementary OS 5.1 never boots and goes to busybox shell (initramfs) prompt with the message

> Unable to find a medium containing a live file system

Please note that I have verified the iso for shasum and it is ok.

Also please note that I can boot into elementary OS hera using usb (rufus created) with no problems. Thats how I was able to install it.

Another important point is I am able to boot into elementary OS juno iso with same kind of grub entry with the iso name changed and able to boot into it.
So I can come to a conclusion that My bios and grub parameters are ok for elementary OS juno and not for elementary OS hera.

I wish to know whether there are any changes to hera w.r.t iso booting using grub or am I doing anything wrong?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You haven't specified _how_ it fails. Does GRUB complain about something? Does it just hang there silently? Something different?

Comment: Hi jmc, Thanks for the response. I am not sure whether I can say grub complains. But the booting iso process ends with a initramfs prompt with the message "Unable to find a medium....". And I need to give reboot command or press ctrl alt del to reboot.

Comment: I would guess the system is unable to mount the root device. You may need to pass an indication of where the root device can be found on the Linux kernel command line, not just to GRUB. See [the documented Linux boot parameters](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bootparam.7.html): it may be enough to set `root=/dev/disk/by-uuid/f3db7e9a-1e71-4493-b26c-4b092a1e172e`.